# Loading a page in another page via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I made an Ajax chat in a PHP page and everything is running fine and smooth.
Then I try to adopt this chat on another page in a div that pops up (via css on z-index).

This is the code:

```
function showChat(username){
                    var
                        $http,
                        $self = arguments.callee;

                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                        try {
                            $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
                        } catch(e) {
                            $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                        }
                    }

                    if ($http) {
                        $http.onreadystatechange = function()
                        {
                            if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                                window.parent.document.getElementById('chatbox').style.display = "block";
                                window.parent.document.getElementById('chatbox').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
                            }
                        };
                        $http.open('GET', "dashchat/chatbox.php?chatWith="+username, true);
                        $http.send(null);
                    }
        }
```

The div shows and the text box of the chat shows but the messages doesn't
The ajax doesn't run and when I submit a message it redirects to my sendmessage.php
any ideas?

Comment: And what response you are getting?

Comment: I am getting my php page but the ajax isn't running

Comment: but if  i go to that chat page itself it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function showChat(username) {
    var 
                        $http,
                        $self = arguments.callee;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e) {
            $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
    }

    if ($http) {
        $http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ($http.readyState == 4) {
                window.parent.document.getElementById('chatbox').style.display = "block";
                window.parent.document.getElementById('chatbox').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
            }
        };
        $http.open('GET', "dashchat/chatbox.php?chatWith=" + username, true);
        $http.send(null);
    }
}
```